# Check that all texts inside one element are the same in Protractor

Tags: javascript, jquery, protractor, element

I've tried to find a logic and code for this scenario but the code doesn't work. It's a bit complicated but I'd like to get all the "summary" elements and check that they are all returned so I can therefore find out if the order status is correct. Although I couldn't quite figure out how to get all the items statuses and check if either one of them are not in status "Returned" or if all of them are especially without any classes. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Html:

```
2 scenarios
Scenario 1:

<summary>Order Status:<span id="status_returned">Returned</span></summary>

<summary>Item Status:<span>Returned</span></summary>

<summary>Item Status:<span>Returned</span></summary>

<summary>Item Status:<span>Returned</span></summary>

Scenario 2:

<summary>Order Status:<span id="status_complete">Complete</span></summary>

<summary>Item Status:<span>Returned</span></summary>

<summary>Item Status:<span>Collected</span></summary>

<summary>Item Status:<span>Returned</span></summary>
```

Protractor:

```
 var checkStatuses = element.all(by.cssContainingText('summary', 'Returned')).isPresent();
    checkStatuses.each(function(checkStatus) {
            if (checkStatus) {
                console.log("Checking if order status is Returned..");
                element(by.css('[id="status_returned"]')).waitReady().then(function(isResult) {
                    if (isResult) {
                        console.log("Order Status: Returned (PASS)");
                    } else {
                        throw "Error: Order Status is NOT Returned";
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log("Checking if item status is Returned..");
                element(by.css('[id="status_complete"]')).waitReady().then(function(isResult) {
                    if (isResult) {
                        console.log("Item(s) Status: Returned (PASS)");
                    } else {
                        throw "Error: Item(s) Status is NOT Returned";
                    }
                });
            }
        }),
        function(err) {
            throw err;
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code snippet. Install 'q' package as the following code snippet uses 'q' package.

```
var statusObjects = element.all(by.css('summary span'));
statusObjects.then(function(items) {
    var statusPromises = [];
    items.forEach((item) => {
        statusPromises.push(item.getAttribute('innerHTML'));        
    });
    var Q = require('q');
    Q.allResolved(statusPromises).then((results) => {
        var allStatusesAreReturned = true, noOfMismatches = 0;
        for(let i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
            if(results[i].state == 'fulfilled' && results[i].value != 'Returned') {
                allStatusesAreReturned = false;             
                noOfMismatches++;
            } 
        }
        if(allStatusesAreReturned) {
            console.log('All Statuses are returned');
        } else {
            console.log('Mismatch of status Returned in :'+noOfMismatches+' number of occurrences');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this one did it!